# Как выполнять одинаковые действия перед каждым тестом

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-unittest

```
 import unittest
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 import time

 class TestSelenium(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_authorization(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get('https://{url}/')
        time.sleep(3)
        log = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/a')
        log.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        login_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Username')
        login_input.send_keys('111111111')
        login_password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Password')
        login_password.send_keys('111111111')
        log_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/button[1]')
        log_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.assertTrue('Press to start' in driver.page_source)
        driver.close()
```

У меня есть тест автоматизации, суть теста проверить автризацию, я хочу ещё создавать другие функции которые будут выполныять иные тесты, но вот проблема, каждый раз мне необходимо в каждый тест добавлять ещё и авторизацию, код просто не читабелен, можно ли до прогона любого другога теста, запускать сразу самый первый ?? Если да, то как, может будут советы по автоматизации, фреймворкам, методам и подходам приветствуются

Answer (score 1):

Имплементировать функцию [setUp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp).

И почитать что-нибудь про организацию тестов. Ту же [документацию к unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-tests), например.